# SELECT unique Product information of Catalog in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, replace

I have a Table with some Catalog of products. The table have an main shop that say the price for all the products. For example for main shop the IDShop is 9999 and one product can be Red Card = $10 with original OriginIDProduct=101.

```
IDShop=9999
Price=10
OriginIDProduct=101
```

The rest of the shops included a little different information like diferent description or different price, etc.

Supposed for example this data:

```
IDShop=1
Price=12
OriginIDProduct=101
```

Both in the same table, remember...

I need to SELECT the products like is from the shop 9999 but if exist the product with shop 1 don't return the information for this product of shop 9999.

In this case for this product the SELECT return the record

```
IDShop=1
Price=12
OriginIDProduct=101
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This will show each product, with its price from shop 1 if it exists, otherwise it will default to shop 9999.

```
SELECT IFNULL(t2.IDShop, t1.IDShop) AS IDShop,
       IFNULL(t2.Price, t1.Price) AS Price,
       IFNULL(t2.OriginIDProduct, t1.OriginIDProduct) AS OriginIDProduct
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.OriginIDProduct = t2.OriginIDProduct AND t2.IDShop = 1
WHERE t1.IDShop = 9999
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca86b6/1

Comment: This solution works but can be exist new products that not correspond to main shop. For example, the client add new products differents to Main shop that like to sale. For example, respect to the sample of the link, a new product like VALUES(1, 33, 100001). Any idea to return this product to in this select

Comment: for that you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but MySQL doesn't support it. If you search SO, you'll find workarounds. It should be straightforward for any competent programmer to modify my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, i found the solution with the use of UNION ALL and OriginIDProduct=0. Because All products are new customer do not correspond with the main shop. I publish the answer. Thanks, Oscar.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    IDShop, Price, OriginIDProduct
from 
    table
where
    IDShop <> 9999 
    or
    (   
        IDShop = 9999 
        and not exists (select IDShop from table where IDShop <> 9999)
    )
```

Comment: This solution not solve the problem. This return only the products for the IDShop <> 9999. But need to return the products of IDShop=9999 with the records replaced of IDShop=1 for the same products. Example IDProduct=1 (the information of shop 9999), IDProduct=2 (exist in 9999 and 1. The record of 1 replace the 9999, IDProduct=3 (the information of 99999. Remember that 9999 is the main

Comment: @OscarFernándezArcís Sorry, haven't understood your need yet. Anyway, it's not true that my query return only products where IDShop <> 9999. Take a look at the "OR" condition.

Comment: Sorry but your solution return:  

`IDSHOP PRICE ORIGINIDPRODUCT`  
`1 12 101`  
`1 50 103`

With the SQL Sample of Barmar (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca86b6/1)

The correct return is:

`IDSHOP PRICE ORIGINIDPRODUCT`
`1 12 101`
`9999 14 102`
`1 50 103`

And if the client add a new product without relation of the main shop need to return:

`IDSHOP PRICE ORIGINIDPRODUCT`
`1 12 101`
`9999 14 102`
`1 50 103`
`1 33 0`

Regards, Oscar.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with help of Barma found the solution, is this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t2.IDShop, t1.IDShop) AS IDShop,
       IFNULL(t2.Price, t1.Price) AS Price,
       IFNULL(t2.OriginIDProduct, t1.OriginIDProduct) AS OriginIDProduct
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.OriginIDProduct = t2.OriginIDProduct AND t2.IDShop = 1
WHERE t1.IDShop = 9999
UNION ALL
SELECT IDShop, Price, OriginIDProduct FROM table WHERE IDShop=1 AND OriginIDProduct=0
```

Thanks to all.
Regards, Oscar.